# Pandas DataFrame str.split() error : Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series of data named university_towns. Using pd.Dataframe to turn it into a Dataframe:

```
town_df = pd.DataFrame(university_towns,columns=['State','RegionName'])
```

Output:

```
State         RegionName
Alabama       Auburn (Auburn University
Alabama       Florence (University of North Alabama
Alabama       Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University
Alabama       Livingston (University of West Alabama
Alabama       Montevallo (University of Montevallo
```

With DataFrame above, I try to split RegionName into Region and University using code below:

```
town_df[['Region','University']]= town_df['RegionName'].str.split('(',1).tolist()
```

it returns:

> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

However, when I try below code, I get the correct split.

```
town_df[['Region','University']]= pd.DataFrame(town_df['RegionName'].str.split('(',1).tolist())
```

Output:

```
State     Region         University
Alabama   Auburn         Auburn University
Alabama   Florence       University of North Alabama
Alabama   Jacksonville   Jacksonville State University
Alabama   Livingston     University of West Alabama
Alabama   Montevallo     University of Montevallo
```

The only difference between these 2 lines of code is by including pd.DataFrame before the split, why do I have the add pd.DataFrame before the split.

Comment: `town_df[['Region','University']]= town_df['RegionName'].str.split('(', expand=True)`

Comment: 1st one was a list with lists of size 2, 2nd where you turned that list of lists into a df.